# c# program runs improperly after disconnecting socket

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

I'm new to C# and trying to write a Server-Client messaging application, I've done it with some cheating from internet but now I have a problem which I'm thinking over for a couple of days. My problem is, when I disconnect my client, and then reconnect it without stopping server, it (or they - because it's a multi-client app) can receive messages from the server but can not send messages (at least it does seem so in the messagebox of the server). I couldn't find out what the problem is.

Here is the codes: (not exactly all of the lines but the crucial parts)

**Server:**

```
public void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
        strName = "Server";
    }
    catch {}
}

private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);

        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
        
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);             
    }
    catch {}
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);
        Data msgToSend = new Data();
        byte[] message;

        msgToSend.cmdCommand = msgReceived.cmdCommand;
        msgToSend.strName = msgReceived.strName;

        while (true)
        {
            switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
            {
                case Command.Login:
                    ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo
                    {
                        socket = clientSocket,
                        strName = msgReceived.strName
                    };
                    clientList.Add(clientInfo);
                            
                    flag = true;
                    msgToSend.strMessage = "<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " has joined the room>>>";
                    break;

                case Command.Logout:
                    int nIndex = 0;
                    foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                    {
                        if (client.socket == clientSocket)
                        {
                            clientList.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                            break;
                        }
                        ++nIndex;
                    }
                    clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    clientSocket.Close();

                    flag = true;
                    msgToSend.strMessage = "<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " has left the room>>>";
                    break;

                case Command.Message:
                    if (msgReceived.strMessage == "**disconnect**")
                    {
                        msgReceived.cmdCommand = Command.Logout;
                        disconnect = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        msgToSend.strMessage = msgReceived.strMessage;

                    flag = false;
                    break;

                case Command.List:
                    msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.List;
                    msgToSend.strName = null;
                    msgToSend.strMessage = null;

                    foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                    {
                        msgToSend.strMessage += client.strName + "*";
                    }

                    flag = false;
                    message = msgToSend.ToByte();
                    clientSocket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientSocket);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (msgToSend.cmdCommand != Command.List)
        {
            message = msgToSend.ToByte();

            foreach (ClientInfo clientInfo in clientList)
            {
                if ((clientInfo.socket != clientSocket || msgToSend.cmdCommand != Command.Login) && !disconnect)
                {
                    clientInfo.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientInfo.socket);
                }
            }

            if (flag)
                msgBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\r\n", msgToSend.strMessage));
            else
                msgBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", msgToSend.strName, msgToSend.strMessage));
        }

        if (msgReceived.cmdCommand != Command.Logout && !disconnect)
        {
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

**Client:**

```
private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
        strName = usernameBox.Text.Trim();
    }
    catch {}
}

private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);

        Data msgToSend = new Data
        {
            cmdCommand = Command.Login,
            strName = usernameBox.Text.Trim(),
            strMessage = null
        };
        byte[] b = msgToSend.ToByte();

        clientSocket.BeginSend(b, 0, b.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);

        if (clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            Data msgToSendConn = new Data
            {
                cmdCommand = Command.List,
                strName = strName,
                strMessage = null
            };
            byteData = msgToSendConn.ToByte();

            clientSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);

            byteData = new byte[1024];
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);

            Active(true);
        }
    }
    catch {}
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);

        switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
        {
            case Command.Login:
                clientListBox.Items.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                break;

            case Command.Logout:
                clientListBox.Items.Remove(msgReceived.strName);
                break;

            case Command.Message:
                break;

            case Command.List:
                clientListBox.Items.AddRange(msgReceived.strMessage.Split('*'));
                clientListBox.Items.RemoveAt(clientListBox.Items.Count - 1);
                msgBox.Text += "<<<" + strName + " has joined the room>>>\r\n";
                break;
        }

        if (msgReceived.strMessage.Length > 0 && msgReceived.cmdCommand != Command.List)
            msgBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", msgReceived.strName, msgReceived.strMessage));

        byteData = new byte[1024];

        clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }
    catch {}
}

private void connBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...validating ip and port number in textboxes...

    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

    try
    {
        clientSocket.BeginConnect(iPEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
    }
    catch {}

private void disconnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Data msgToSend = new Data
    {
        strName = strName,
        strMessage = "**disconnect**",
        cmdCommand = Command.Message
    };
    byte[] byteData = msgToSend.ToByte();

    clientSocket.Send(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    clientSocket.Close();
}

private void sendMsgBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (sendMsgBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Data msgToSend = new Data
            {
                strName = strName,
                strMessage = sendMsgBox.Text.Trim(),
                cmdCommand = Command.Message
            };
            byte[] byteData = msgToSend.ToByte();

            clientSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
            sendMsgBox.Clear();
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

**The Data class and Command enum which are same in both Server and Client:**

```
enum Command
{
    Login,
    Logout,
    Message,
    List,
    Null
}

class Data
{
    public string strName;
    public string strMessage;
    public Command cmdCommand;

    public Data()
    {
        cmdCommand = Command.Null;
        strMessage = null;
        strName = null;
    }

    public Data(byte[] data)
    {
        cmdCommand = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        int nameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
        int msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

        if (nameLen > 0)
            strName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12, nameLen);
        else
            strName = null;

        if (msgLen > 0)
            strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12 + nameLen, msgLen);
        else
            strMessage = "";
    }

    public byte[] ToByte()
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        if (strMessage != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strMessage.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName));

        if (strMessage != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage));

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two separate sockets, you can use the same one to send and receive? To be honest, not clear why you are using bare sockets anyway, probably better to just use a proper protocol like HTTPS. Also, instead of using the old `Begin` `End` methods, you should just use `async` `await`. And note that `Receive` will not necessarily receive the full amount of bytes you ask, and it may not be a whole message, it may be part of one or more messages, so you need some kind of framing mechanism to split it up.

Comment: @Charlieface I was doing an intership until 1 week ago, and they told me to write a chat application using sockets, they said it will be good for learning. That's why I use sockets. And I just learned C# and not so good at it, so I had to copy someone's code on internet and tried to understand which code does what. Now, I want to proceed with the code I wrote in the question; so, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Well it's not great code, so maybe find a different template to begin with. There are quite a number of fundamental issues with your code that it really needs a complete rewrite. You may want to have a look at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html Consider using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` which abstract away a lot of the complications.

Comment: Fromcmd.exe use '>netstat -a'  on both client and server and check status of the connection.  The connection did not close and you cannot connect a second time using the same Source IP, Destination IP, and port when the port is already in use.

Comment: @jdweng I forgot to mention it. I did that and it work seamlessly. When I connect to server, it shows the ip:port number and ESTABLISHED text, and when I disconnect the client, the ip:port number and disappears from that list, without any TIME_WAIT sign. So, there is no problem with connecting-disconnecting the client. I have problem with just receiving after reconnected.

Comment: You mean the server has TIME_WAIT.  TIME_WAIT is a bug that exists in TCP from development in early 1970s.  TCP every datagram has an ACK.  When both the client and server attempts to close simultaneously one of the ACK do not occur because of a race condition.  The solution is to always close a connection only from the client (not both the client and server).  The ASYNC Listener will stay open after a client closes connection and then accept new multiple connections. From server remove :                     clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    clientSocket.Close();

Comment: @jdweng I think I misstate it, sorry. I mean, I can successfully close the client. The server doesn't have any TIME_WAIT bug. I know most people encounter this issue, I encountered it too, but I fixed it. That's why I wanted to mention it. There is no such problem. The only problem is the non-operating receive function after reconnecting.

Comment: Where is the Accept method on the listener?  The Accept should call the receive.  See : https://gist.github.com/leandrosilva/656054?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng OK, now I'm starting to understand something. I'll try to fix my code with the link you gave. But what I don't understand is, the program works correctly when it is first opened and connected. Either server and client can send and receive messages. What changes after reconnecting? If it needs a method that call Receive method, it must need every time, not just after reconnecting.

Comment: Not sure but suspect the constructor automatically creates the first Accept method.  When you close the connection you loose the Accept method and cannot receive a second Accept.